# How can we read all mp3 files in a mounted(Raspberry pi) usb in Qt toolkit (Qt) application

Tags: linux, qt, raspberry-pi, media-queries, media

I am trying to create an music application for my Raspberry pi, I have finished my player UI. Now i need to detect the USB which is mounted in the raspberry pi and read all the mp3 files from the USB. Is there any example which i can refer to for implementing this.

Somewhere i read about [solid.kde](https://solid.kde.org/)  library but no examples are there to actually start implementation, Any guides or example links would be appreciated.

Comment: When you say "QT" are you referring to the Qt application toolkit (Qt), or QuickTime (QT)? Likewise, when you say "the USB" are you referring to a USB flash drive or something else? If it's a flash drive, what filesystem is it using?

Comment: @MrEricSir i was refering to Qt application toolkit (Qt), and i want to access the files in the usb flash drive not sure what kind of file system we should use to easily access files in flash drive usb.

Comment: Do you have to take care of the mounting itself, too? If not, you could simply read `/etc/mtab` and `/etc/ftab` to locate the mounted drive. (And use `QDirIterator` to traverse the mounted drive)

Answer (score 1):

I did that on another board a couple of years ago. What you can do is using dbus to get notifications about plugged in devices and mounting. You can do all via dbus and QtDbus using this code, which is very simple: https://github.com/Razor-qt/razor-qt/blob/master/libraries/razormount/rzmountproviders_udisks2.cpp. You have add and remove notifications and a few methods to mount and unmount. I think this can be done also on the Pi as dbus is available.